# When writing from list to file, final output misses some members of the list

Tags: python

There is a list where each member is an 8 digit string.

```
values = [ '12345678', '23848238', '23441236', ...
```

I want to write all of those on a .txt like the following:

```
123456782384823823441236...
```

I tried to do so with the following code:

```
x = open('a.txt', 'w')
for l in range(len(values)):
    for m in range(0,7):
        current = values[l]
        x.write(current[m])
        x.seek((l*8)+(m))
```

The result is a .txt missing the very first digit (in the example, the '1'), and then missing every eighth digit all the way up to the end. I have tried messing with the way I am indexing everything (and did get the very first digit to show up) but it still misses every eighth digit.

Comment: Why are you iterating over a range and seeking and all that stuff rather than just writing each value the normal way?

Comment: What is the normal way? I started using Python 15 minutes ago so I'm not that acquainted with it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Python optimizes the common case, such as writing a sequence of strings to a file. For the normal way of doing that, see my answer below.

Comment: If you'd like to indicate a question as solved, accept the answer that solved it rather than adding a tag to the title. This will help future readers.

Comment: It did work! Nice, thanks. Oh and yes I know about accepting the answers: the site just wouldn't let me accept it for 5 or so minutes. Why is that? Oh and then I added the '(SOLVED)' tag because I have had suggestions to add it in a previous answered question - I'm just going by what I've seen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the first character because your `seek` is at the end of the loop - causing you to overwrite the first character in the second iteration.

You're missing every 8th character because `range(0,7)` is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

You should really stop writing data like this, just output the items one by one as @TigerhawkT3 suggested - no seeking at all.

Comment: So the range is exclusive to the seven, or is the indexing different in this case than the one from strings/lists? And oh yes, now I see the `seek` at the end of the loop really was responsible for the missing 1st digit. Thanks for pinpointing that. What is wrong with seeking and etc..., if I may ask?

Comment: It's just not necessary. You're seeking to where the file pointer is located anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to check lengths and seek and all that if you just want to write all the strings in that list to a file.

```
with open('a.txt', 'w') as output:
    for item in values:
        output.write(item)
```